# Find, chown and exclude directories

Tags: find, chown

I would like to change the ownership of all files and directories but exclude some directories:

```
find -user test ! -path "./dir1/*" ! -path "./dir2/*" -exec chown -R root:root {} \;
```

The ownership of the excluded directories is still changed?

Regards

Comment: You're missing an argument: the directory to start the find in.  Since that defaults to `.`, if it happens to be owned by user `test`, it will match, and then you're recursively chowning everything under that anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find . \( -path ./dir1 -o -path ./dir2 \) -prune -o -user test -exec chown root:root {} \;`

Personally, for performance reasons, I prefer:

`find . \( -path ./dir1 -o -path ./dir2 \) -prune -o -user test -print0 | xargs -0 chown root`

Comment: You have this backward. This will work *only* on `dir1` and `dir2`. The OP want to work on everything *except* those two.

Comment: No. Doing -prune means exclude dir1 and dir2. The or (-o) means if you didn't prune them like you did with dir1 and dir2, then do the chown.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Anyway, this still includes the base dirs in the output and will `chown` them.

Comment: Yes, it includes . and other directories in . I thought that was asked.

Comment: What I meant was that `./dir1` and `./dir2` will still be listed by this and such `chown`ed. It's not recursive anymore, but still.

Comment: It has the added bonus (when you use -print0 and xargs -0) of handling files with spaces in it.

Comment: Did you try it? I did. It works fine. I did, in a directory, `find . \( -path ./dir1 -o -path ./dir2 \) -prune -o -type d -print` and all the directories where I was printed except dir1 and dir2.

Comment: Yes, and here it prints the base names.

Comment: What's your OS? I just tried it on OSX and Ubuntu 13.10 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find . -user test | grep -v '^./dir1\|^./dir2'
```

to check if the list is correct and

```
find . -user test | grep -v '^./dir1\|^./dir2' | xargs chown root:root
```

to do the rename.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X you can use the following version of the command posted by Sven:

```
find . | grep -v '^./@R*' | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 chown root:root
```